# Calling functions before subscribing

Tags: http, angular, rxjs

I have a http call to a remote server using the `angular2/http` and thats all working awesomely and such. But I'm having trouble with using the observables that it returns.

When I do my http calls, I'm going through 3 different components.

(for ease here ill just make the calls 3 different methods instead as it works out the same)

What I want to know if its possible to do, is use subscribe twice on the same observable or if there is a way that I can call some functions so I can add logging in the request rather than needing to add it at every location that I make a http call.

```
  request(type: RequestMethod, url: string, data: any) {

    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    let req: RequestOptions;
    let headers = new Headers();

    for (let key in data) {
      params.set(key, data[key]);
    }

    if (type === 0) {
      req = new RequestOptions({
        method: type,
        search: params
      });
    } else {
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      req = new RequestOptions({
        method: type,
        body: params.toString(),
        headers: headers
      });
    }

    console.log('Http Request: ' + url);
    console.log(req);
    return this.http.request(this.testUrl + url, req)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
      // .subscribe(                                  
      //   data => {                                 
      //     console.log('Data Return for ' + url); 
      //     console.log(data.data);
      //     // return data;  //i removed this subscribe so i can 
      //   },                //pass the map back through and
      //   err => {          //use the subscribe later in the initial call
      //     this.logError(url, err);
      //   },
      //   () => {
      //     if (afterSuccess) {
      //       afterSuccess();
      //     }
      //     console.log('Completed '+ url);
      //   }
      // );
  }

  logError(url: string, err: any) {
    console.log('Error in call: ' + url);
    console.log(err);
  }

  get(url: string, data: any) {
    return this.request(RequestMethod.Get, url, data);
  }

  post(url: string, data: any) {
    return this.request(RequestMethod.Post, url, data);
  }

  emailExists(email_address: string, user_type?: string) {
    let data: any = {};

    data.email_address = email_address;
    data.service_provider_id = this.service_provider_id;

    if (user_type) {
      data.user_type = user_type;
    }

    return this.get('emails/email-address/exists', data);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.emailExists('an.email@gmail.com').subscribe(data => {
      this.email = data.data;
      console.log('in Signin');
      console.log(this.email);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    }, () => {

    });
  }
```

In the `request` method I want to be able to call a console.log to print out the url that was used and print the data received from the server or any errors.
I know I could add it to the success and error portions of the subscribe in the `emailExists()` call in `ngOnInit()` but that would mean I would need to put those in every single call throughout the app.

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage the `do`, `catch` and `finally` operators of observables to do that.

Here is a sample:

```
return this.http.request(this.tpayUrl + url, req)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .do(data => {                                 
       console.log('Data Return for ' + url); 
       console.log(data.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      this.logError(url, err);
      return Observable.throw(err);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      if (afterSuccess) {
        afterSuccess();
      }
      console.log('Completed '+ url);
    });
```